# How to suppress warning "ZipDeploy Validation WARNING: It is recommended to set app setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

In my Azure DevOps pipeline, I'm deploying a logic app on Azure but I get this warning:

```
##[warning]"ZipDeploy Validation WARNING: It is recommended to set app setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1 unless you are targeting one of the following scenarios: 
1. Using portal editing.
2. Running post deployment scripts.
3. Need write permission in wwwroot. 
4. Using custom handler with special requirements. 
NOTE: If you decide to update app setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1, you will have to re-deploy your code."
```

Is it possible to suppress this warning?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the application settings to allow zip deploy like below:-

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2

inputs:

# TODO: Fill in with the name of your Azure service connection

azureSubscription: ''

scriptType: 'bash'

scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'

inlineScript: |

az functionapp config appsettings set --name $(LAname) --resource-group $(resourceGroupName) --settings "BLOB_CONNECTION_RUNTIMEURL=$(blobendpointurl)"

az functionapp config appsettings set --name $(LAname) --resource-group $(resourceGroupName) --settings "WORKFLOWS_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME=$(resourceGroupName)"

az functionapp config appsettings set --name $(LAname) --resource-group $(resourceGroupName) --settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1

addSpnToEnvironment: true

useGlobalConfig: true
```

Powershell task with app service plan

```yaml
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MyAzureSubscription'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      Set-AzWebApp -Name MyWebApp -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroup -AppSettings @{'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'='1'}
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

Make sure you change the deployment-method in your YAML pipeline to deploymentMethod: ‘runFromPackage’ instead of ‘zipDeploy’ like below:-

[image]

To :-

[image]

And then run your pipeline to allow zip deployment of Azure Logic app.

Reference:-

[AzureFunctionApp@1 Gives a warning about something it removes itself · Issue #17580 · microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17580)

Comment: The downside of this is that it makes the logic app readonly in the Azure Portal, which I don't want in my dev environment